# How to remove or disable a SharePoint email notification in Microsoft 365

Tags: sharepoint

I created an email notification in SharePoint 365 recently for changes to a library or folder, and I get emails constantly when files are added in any folder or subfolder. This isn't what I intended, so I want to remove the notification, but I can't find it anywhere.
How can I find the SharePoint email notification I created so that I can remove it?

Comment: Hi, as this isn't a programming related question it may be a better fit at SuperUser.com. :)

Comment: I didn't realize that existed.  I can ask there, thanks.